# Doctrine/MySQL mediumtext + unncessary ALTER TABLEs

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, dbal

Running on mysql 5.7 + Doctrine 2.7/DBAL 2.9, with:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Entity {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100000, nullable=true)
     */
    private $bigText;
}
```

orm:schema-tool:create creates the table Entity:

```
CREATE TABLE `Entity` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bigText` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

However, the schema-tool considers the table in need of update, running `orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql` gives:

```
ALTER TABLE Entity CHANGE bigText bigText MEDIUMTEXT DEFAULT NULL;
```

Executing the update works fine, but doesn't help: it will still think the table needs updating.

I've tracked the issue to Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Comparator's diffColumn method where the PlatformOptions of the current and the to-be column definition are compared. The to-be column has no PlatformOptions (which makes sense, as it's not on the platform yet, I suppose), while the current column does have them, namely charset and collation, in my test case here the defaults:  `['charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci']`, which are set on the Column object by `Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\MySqlSchemaManager->_getPortableTableColumnDefinition()`.

Poking around a bit in the source, I've found I can use EventListeners: because `Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\AbstractSchemaManager->_getPortableTableColumnList()` will emit an `onSchemaColumnDefinition` event and if I set `$event->preventDefault()` in there and create my own Column object and use `$event->setColumn($column)`, I can circumvent `MySqlSchemaManager->_getPortableTableColumnDefinition()`. Or, I can go and fiddle with the other side and change the Schema created from the Classes / annotations and use `postGenerateSchemaTable` (which is much easier and feels less weird than messing with `onSchemaColumnDefinition`).
While I've learned a tiny bit more about internal flows, this feels way too complicated to handle mediumtext in MySQL without creating unnecessary ALTER TABLEs all the time.

Of course, I can sidestep the issue entirely by using type="text" instead of type="string" + a fixed length (which I've realized while browing issues here before asking this), but out of curiosity: am I missing something fundamental for dealing with fixed length fields in MySQL that fall into mediumtext length?